# Send JavaScript variable to HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="value1">Introduce value</label>
        <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1" value="" />            
    </div>

    <div class="button-block">
        <input type="submit" value="Click" />
    </div>

    <div id="output">
        <h2>Result:</h2>
        <textarea name="result" id="result"></textarea>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to get the value that is introduced in value1 and when the submit is clicked to put that value in the output. So I wrote in script.js the following code but somehow it doesn't work.

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var val = document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML;

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = val;
};
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use .value property of the input field instead of innerHTML. so it would be:

```
var val = document.getElementById('value1').value;
```

and also, since you're executing it when the page loads. There will be no value assigned to the input field with id 'value1'. Therefore, you won't get any result.

You can try adding a button with onClick event to execute this function in place of using window.onload

Answer (score 0):

HTML controls you are working on are textboxes, so they have a **value** property, not **innerHTML**.
Use this:

```
var val = document.getElementById('value1').value;
document.getElementById('result').value= val;
```

Answer (score 0):

> when the submit is clicked to put that value in the output

You have chosen wrong event `window.onload`, also you need `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`

**Option 1**: using jQuery, as you already have the import

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
    $('#result').val($('#value1').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<div class="field">
  <label for="value1">Introduce value</label>
  <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1" value="" />
</div>

<div class="button-block">
  <input type="submit" value="Click" />
</div>

<div id="output">
  <h2>Result:</h2>
  <textarea name="result" id="result"></textarea>
</div>
```

**Option 2**: using plain js

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.querySelector('#result').value = document.querySelector('#value1').value;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<div class="field">
  <label for="value1">Introduce value</label>
  <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1" value="" />
</div>

<div class="button-block">
  <input type="submit" value="Click" />
</div>

<div id="output">
  <h2>Result:</h2>
  <textarea name="result" id="result"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the value of an input element using the innerHTML attribute. Use value instead:

```
 var val = documento.getElementById('value1').value;
```

Also you should keep in mind that your function is executed when the page loads, NOT when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not working, because you are calling this function when the window loads, not when the submit button is clicked. Since there is no form, and thus no page loading going on, I'd recommend switching the `<input type="submit" value="Click" />` to a button. They are functionally similar, and visually identical. With the the button, though you could use the `onclick` attribute to call a function when the button is clicked. See below for an example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="field">
        <label for="value1">Introduce value</label>
        <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1" value="" />            
    </div>

    <div class="button-block">
        <button onclick="printOutput()">Click</button>
    </div>

    <div id="output">
        <h2>Result:</h2>
        <textarea name="result" id="result"></textarea>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then in your `script.js` you would have,

```
function printOutput(){
    var val = document.getElementById('value1').value;

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var val = document.getElementById('value1').innerHTML;
        var generateHere = document.getElementById("result");
        generateHere.innerHTML = val;
    }, 2000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: That's interesting. Some explanation of what this code is doing (and how it is different from the OP's code) would be helpful.

Comment: I think your script code is run before load you page DOM.
But using this my script, script is run after 2 second of your page DOM load.
That means script run after DOM load.